# Disable click if I have 2 classes with click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link like this:

```
<a class="delete deletePerson">Delete</a>
```

These 2 classes have click events, `deletePerson` launch ajax event to delete a person in BD and `delete` launch a modal to confirm delete, I want to execute delete and if user press OK do deletePerson function but I don't want use `confirm` or `alert` boxes (I'm using bootstrap modals), How can I do?

I know the better solution is send deletePerson function to confirm modal but I have a lot of cases like this and it will takes too many time...